# Display driver crash and restart when viewing PDF in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader, display-driver

I experience occationally (quite often, but not consistent) that the display driver crashes and restarts when I have a PDF open in Adobe Reader (version 9.4.5).

My display is NVIDIA. I also have 2 monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in a [thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/831534) on Adobe Forums that so far seems to have fixed the issue.

[image: Turn off 2D acceleration in Adobe Reader]

I have tested to turn it on and off, and it seems like it crashes if I have two pdf documents opened and then scroll. This only happens when 2D acceleration is turned on, so turning that off seems to fix this problem.